# Windows Forms small MenuItem hitbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using `MenuItem.DrawItem` to change `MenuItem`'s appearance based on the fact whether user either hovers or select it. Unfortunatelly the hitbox seems too small. Here's my drawing code.

```
private void DrawCustomMenuItem(object sender,
DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    MenuItem customItem = (MenuItem) sender;
    System.Drawing.Brush aBrush = System.Drawing.Brushes.DarkMagenta;
    Font aFont = new Font("Arial", 10,
        FontStyle.Italic, GraphicsUnit.Point);
    SizeF stringSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(
        customItem.Text, aFont);

    Pen p = new Pen(Color.Aqua, 2);
    if ((e.State & DrawItemState.HotLight) == DrawItemState.HotLight
        || (e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
        p = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(customItem.Text, aFont,
        aBrush, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y);
    e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(p,
        new Rectangle(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y,
            (int) stringSize.Width,
            (int) stringSize.Height));
}
```

It only changes color when mouse is nearby left edge of the item. It isn't surprising I guess. I have no code that changes hitbox's dimensions and it is using the default one and I am drawing outside of it. I really have no idea how to approach it. I thought I should use `MenuItem.Size` to achieve that. But this property doesn't exist.

EDIT:
Ok, I got it. It's all about `MeasureItem` event. But another problem came up. The `MeasureItemEventArgs.Graphics.MeasureString()` seems to return too big width for the text. Here are my current functions:

```
private void Mitem2OnMeasureItem(object sender, MeasureItemEventArgs e)
{
    MenuItem item = sender as MenuItem;
    if (item == null) return;
    var size = e.Graphics.MeasureString(item.Text, f);
    e.ItemHeight = (int) size.Height;
    e.ItemWidth = (int) size.Width;
}

private void Mitem2OnDrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    MenuItem item = sender as MenuItem;
    if (item == null) return;

    SizeF size = e.Graphics.MeasureString(item.Text, f);

    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(
        (e.State & DrawItemState.HotLight) == DrawItemState.HotLight ? Brushes.CornflowerBlue : Brushes.Aqua,
        e.Bounds);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(item.Text, f, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y);

    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}
```

This is how it looks like

[image]

Comment: Use [`MenuStrip`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/menustrip)

Comment: @RezaAghaei I am not asking for how to get this done. Rather I want to know what is happening under the hood that is preventing me from achieving the effect I want.

Answer (score 0):

To get a better measurement use the overload of [MeasureString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142108(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes [StringFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.stringformat(v=vs.110).aspx) class:

```
e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
var size = e.Graphics.MeasureString(
    item.Text, 
    aFont, 
    new Point(1,1), 
    StringFormat.GenericTypographic
    );
```

Notice the use of the TextRenderingHint with a value of AntiAlias that is set on the Graphics object.

You'll still have a slightly bigger bounding box but in my test the box is 5 pixels less wide with this code instead of your code.